# Why does nginx gives only one final certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I installed my certificate but encountered `incomplete chain` error at ssllabs.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /var/www/ssl/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/domain.key;
```

`domain.crt` contains a single certificate. Then I created `domain.bundle` as `cat domain.crt domain.med domain.root > domain.bundle` and set

```
ssl_certificate     /var/www/ssl/domain.bundle;
```

Then I reboot nginx, then server, but I still have incomplete chain error.

`openssl s_client -connect domain.ru:443` gives just one certificate in `Certificate chain`.

How can I make nginx to return the whole chain? Is it some kind of a cache?

`/var/www/ssl/domain.bundle` does contain three certificates.

Comment: Check `domain.bundle` to make sure the BEGIN and END markers are on separate lines. I had an intermediate certificate with no terminating newline, so `cat` did not create a suitable bundle. Also, you do not need the `root` in the bundle, as the client browser already knows that.

Comment: SO helps. The file is OK, but I found that there are two `server` sections, and I forgot to fix the second one. Thanks for a target!